# Scons Build Dependency Optimziation?

Tags: scons

Well i have a build setup of 2 projects, one project takes .xml files from a directory and processes them into header files. These files are then used by the second project. Is there any way to check if his project needs to be re-run (the .xml files were modified or a new one was added)?

Comment: Please correct me, if I got it wrong: In project1 you do *.xml->*.h, and in project2 you're using the headers as created in project1. How exactly is project2 using the headers? Is it a standard C/CPP project, which scans for implicit dependencies automatically?

Comment: The headers get put into the include/ folder for the project, the generated header files contents are just structures mostly. The problem is creating the header files, i don't want to create them every build as some are quite large and take some time to create. But when i make changes to the .xml file, i want it to run, so checking on the header files to see if it needs to be built, if that's what you were thinking, wouldn't work i don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just combine the two projects into one common source tree, and one single SConstruct (with as many SConscripts as you like in the subfolders, that get included by SConscript(file) ).

Then ensure that the header files in the include/ folder are always tried to be built, e.g. by adding them as default targets with env.Default().

SCons will only call each conversion *.xml->*.h when the corresponding source XML file has changed its content.

Comment: It doesn't doesn't do them one by one, it does as a batch. The program ensures inheritance so they can't be processed one by one. I am essentially calling `genheaders <input_dir> <output_dir>` from scons, how would it know about the xml files with only that?

Comment: You would write an Emitter for this specific build step, which would then internally expand the <input_dir> <output_dir> to the full list of targets and sources (see http://www.scons.org/wiki/ToolsForFools ). Then SCons knows which files get created by your build step, and can link them properly to the following stage of your build (= project2).

Comment: I'm not sure the emitter will work, as it relies on input and that input generates a list of expected files. If i do `source = "mydir/"` i have no way of generating the targets that it should except, as the output depends on the contents of the those files, which is only known after the command is executed but Scon's emitter needs to know before the file is executed.

Comment: Well, you say that the list of created files is "expected", so there seems to be some underlying rule describing which output files should exist after the build step is executed. If this isn't known, then you don't have any infos about your dependencies...so no chance to improve how they are detected. Can you post how your current build step (builder?) for the *.xml->*.h conversion looks like?

Comment: Well to know the contents, you'd have to parse the xml files. I did something like this, as one header file is always built regardless of the inputs: `env.Command(target = Glob("include/path/*.h") + [ "include/path/expected.h" ], source = Glob("intputs/*.json"), "command hardcoded_path hardcoded_path")`

Comment: Yes, you have to parse. This is what the Java builder in SCons does, for example. It parses the source files, to look for anonymous and inner classes that would generate additional *.class files. You somehow have to get this information into your build system, else you can't work with it properly...and special operations like "clean" or "variant dirs" (or both combined) will likely fail later on. If you'd try to manage your build in make, you'd have to do the same...by writing a program that parses your input file and then spits out the *.dep files for make.